# In The Old Reader, other than drag and dropping, how can I move a feed / subscription to another folder?

Tags: rss-reader, the-old-reader

[The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com/) feed aggregator's '[How To'](http://theoldreader.com/pages/tour) page states that:

> **Organize feeds** - You can drag & drop feeds and folders to change their position.
>   Creating a new feed folder is as easy as dragging a feed to an empty
>   space below your last folder.

Aside from dragging and dropping feeds, is there a way to specify which folder (like by a checkbox, similar to Google Reader) to move a feed to? I can't currently find a way to do this and have to organize by drag and dropping in the meantime.